# UnauthorizedAccess on post build of Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, powershell

I am trying to work on a Windows laptop and setup a `post_build.ps1` after the regular build of Visual Studio in VB.NET

When I run the script on powershell command, it doesn't have any error. But when I do it through Build in Visual Studio, I have this:

`powershell ./_POST_BUILD.ps1 exited with code 1`

If I enable the diagnostic output, I can see through the output this:

```
1>  AuthorizationManager check failed. (TaskId:39)
1>      + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException (TaskId:39)
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess (TaskId:39)
```

What I tried:

1. Set the policies to unrestricted with `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -scope LocalMachine` and `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -scope CurrentUser`
2. Change the post build event in Visual Studio to `Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file "$(SolutionDir)bin\debug\_POST_BUILD.ps1"`
3. Unblock file with right click -> properties -> unblock
4. Run Visual Studio as administrator always

Comment: is that target file/folder read only?

Comment: Folders are read-only. Files are not. When I changed it to unchecked, it turn back to black box for folders only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unblocking the file with Right Click -> Properties -> Unblock -> Apply did not work. I had to run the following in PowerShell:

`unblock-file --path ./_POST_BUILD.ps1`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding debug output to your powershell script. This can help you determine if the script is even starting and hitting an error while it runs, or if the error is in trying to run the script in the first place.

Also, try adding the -ExecutionPolicy switch directly to your powershell.exe arguments to be sure that the execution policy isn't an issue (probably not, if it was you'd get an explicit message telling you that).

Make sure your test run of the script is running under the same user account (probably is) and UAC elevated/not elevated state as Visual Studio (since you tried using VS elevated that is unlkely a problem).

This page (http://tgnp.me/2011/09/powershell-authorizationmanager-check-failed-resolution/) recommends ensuring the WMI service is running.

Answer (score 0):

Copy on Visual Studio Powershell, run and after close VS.
Reopen VS, it worked.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy –ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```